# Nodejs UUIDv4 producing constant id value when used in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, uuid

Recently I noticed that my [UUIDv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) generator is having a high rate of collision. I use it to generate UUIDs for my mongodb objects like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const ObjectSchema = new Schema({
  UUID: { type: String, required: true, default: uuid() },
  ...})
```

## Expected Output

```
[
  {
    UUID: '079f67e1-4532-49fc-b7e6-2e6970c8702f',
    _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fac,

  },
  {
    UUID: 'afbc0fd4-99aa-4d73-88d7-a4724fb3df30',
    _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fad,

  },
  {
    UUID: '39b099b5-9eaf-4ac3-8d4b-1380369090b5',
    _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fae,

  }
]
```

## Actual Result

```
 [
      {
        UUID: '39b099b5-9eaf-4ac3-8d4b-1380369090b5',
        _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fac,

      },
      {
        UUID: '39b099b5-9eaf-4ac3-8d4b-1380369090b5',
        _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fad,

      },
      {
        UUID: '39b099b5-9eaf-4ac3-8d4b-1380369090b5',
        _id: 5e0aa675f900cb561bf51fae,

      }
    ]
```

What I noticed recently is that it gives a constant value more often than not. Usually, a new value is assigned when I restart the server. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: You mean you are getting same value or about 90% of text are same? As per your example all character are same except last one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your code is UUID will be generated one time, and it will use that same default value.

You need to use function form of default like this to generate a different uuid every time:

```js
UUID: { type: String, required: true, default: () => uuid() }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
const foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: () => uuidv4(), // Modify this as a function
    required: true,
  },
  foodName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  daysSinceAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});
```