# how to create custom _id using uuid in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
  _id: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    default: uuid.v4,
  },
```

But the problem is mongoose warns me not to replace the _id.

In another way, I tried creating custom id

```
id: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   unique: true,
   default: uuid.v4,
},
```

But the problem comes with populating the ref documents (can't populate the other models in mongoose).

Now I want to create custom id using UUID but it should work like ObjectId and should allow me to populate the other models.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to define _id in the schema and passing this parameter { _id: false }

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540434/11717458) answer, it is exactly what you want. You need to use String type, and you need to use function form of default.

Comment: We can make _id as String but what about populate function? And also mongoose warns me to not change the _id field.